How to mount a virtual disk inside Azure Container Instance?
I have an Azure SMB File Share which gets mounted inside my Azure Container Instance. Inside the File Share, there's a Virtual Disk file VHD.img which I want to mount.
My container instance Dockerfile ends with this command to mount the VHD and start my application:
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo mount -t auto -o loop /mnt/fileshare/VHD.img /home/user/users/; gunicorn ... [redacted]"]

However, I get this message in the logs:
mount: /home/user/users/: mount failed: Operation not permitted.

And when I connect to my container instance I also cannot mount that VHD no matter what, not even as root, it always says operation not permitted.
My container instance is deployed with --privileged and --add-capabilities ALL, so I should be able to mount, right?
Now some context on why I'm trying to do this:
My application deals with reading and writing lots of small files. I noticed it was performing too slow (like 10 seconds to load the contents of a directory 5MB to memory, while locally it took <0.01 seconds). The Azure Storage diagnostics said my application was indeed too slow and linked me to this documentation, which told me to mount a VHD, which I am trying to do.

The --privileged argument doesn't work on Azure Container Instances. ACI doesn't expose any of the underlying infrastructure to containers. And since VHDs are treated as block devices (as if they're physical disks) you will not be able to mount a VHD inside your container.
That being said, using a VHD may not deliver the performance improvements one may expect from reading that documentation. It really depends on a number of factors.
The main thing you should concern yourself with when working with large numbers of small files over SMB is the level of network latency between the container instance and the storage account.
Let's imagine a scenario where you have ACI in UK South, and Storage Account in East US. Despite Microsoft Azure having a great backbone / global network between regions, there is still latency. Let's just guess that latency in this imaginary scenario is 10ms. You have a folder with 5000 files in, 1KB each, for a total of just short of 5MB. For every file that your application requests :-
Client Request:

The client sends a request to the server to read a file, specifying the file name and path.

Server Response (File Metadata):

The server responds to the client's request with file metadata, such as file size, permissions, and attributes.

Client Acknowledgment:

The client acknowledges the file metadata received from the server.

Data Transfer (File Content):

The server begins transferring the file content to the client in one or more data packets.

Client Confirmation:

Once the file content transfer is complete, the client sends a confirmation message to the server to acknowledge successful receipt of the file data.

Server Acknowledgment:

The server acknowledges the client's confirmation, indicating that the file read operation is complete.

This is at least 6 messages back and forth, and doesn't include other network overhead. So that would be a minimum of 60ms to retrieve one file. Multiply that by 5000 and suddenly the entire operation is taking 30 seconds.
Even if you were to get access to the current preview Premium Files for Azure, which supports metadata caching, unless the significant part of the latency is caused by the storage service (Azure end), you're only going to see a performance increase of maybe around 15%; Using a VHD will not overcome the full issue. I've had to tackle this issue myself when migrating a file server with 6 million files over a VPN connection. In my case I was able to reduce the time by compressing files into Zip archives to reduce the quantity of files, and decompressing them the other end. I don't think you have this luxury in your case.
So, the first thing to check is:
Is my storage account in the same Azure region as my container instance?
If not then moving one to the other may just enhance performance to an acceptable level.
If you want to test a preview premium file share, follow the sign up for public preview link here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/smb-performance#metadata-caching-for-premium-smb-file-shares
All in all, the correct solution likely involves moving away from using files over the network. You may consider using a database instead. A lot of work, I know.

Thank you for the thoughtful response. That is crazy. Yes, I forgot to mention, the storage and container are in the same region. I have tested the premium as well, it halved request timings, but still not good enough.
I would really dislike using a database because my use case needs files written on disk (it involves compiling source files and running static analyzers). Will try that, though. Thanks. If you have other suggestions, please let me know.

Could you try creating a disk in the portal? And adding the disk as persistent storage during container creation, +Create->Disk->Select storage account? If using the az cli, you could try referencing it during container creation az container create \ --resource-group myResourceGroup \ --name myContainer \ --image myDockerImage \ --volume myVolume=/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myAzureDisk:/mnt/mydata:ReadWrite \ --azure-file-volume-mount-path /mnt/myvolume

The --volume argument does not exist.

My bad. It only supports attaching shares, which is the same as mounting inside the container. Please ignore.
